# How to mock a CompletableFuture in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockito, completable-future

We have some code to read data from DynamoDB:

```
suspend fun getKeys(owner: String): Set<String> {
    ...
    val query = ...
    query.subscribe { page -> foo(page) }.await()
    return ...
}
```

The `subscribe{}` above is defined in AWS SDK:

> `default CompletableFuture<Void> subscribe(Consumer<T> consumer)`

I'd like to unit test the logic in this function, for `subscribe` I don't care about it, hopefully just mock and do nothing.

I tried mock a callback in my unit test (irrelevant code removed):

```
class BucketRepoTest(
    @Mock private val query: SdkPublisher<Page<DbBucket>>
) {
    @Test
    fun `get keys should be working`() {
        val callback = mock<(Page<DbBucket>) -> Unit>()
        val result = mock<CompletableFuture<Void>>()
        whenever(query.subscribe(callback)).thenReturn(result)

        runBlocking {
            val keys = data.getKeys("Charlie")
            assert(keys.isEmpty())
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the test I got NPE:

```
query.subscribe { page -> foo(page) } must not be null
java.lang.NullPointerException: query.subscribe { page -> foo(page) } must not be null
    at com.myApp.getKeys(myfile.kt:75)
    at ...
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The result cannot be void.

> val result = mock<CompletableFuture>()

try to create a mock data and pass as result

> val result = the object or data type you want to more
> Example

```
data Result( Charlie = "john", age = "23")
```

then

```
class BucketRepoTest(
@Mock private val query: SdkPublisher<Page<DbBucket>> ) {
@Test
fun `get keys should be working`() {
    val callback = mock<(Page<DbBucket>) -> Unit>()
    val result = Result()
    whenever(query.subscribe(callback)).thenReturn(result)

    runBlocking {
        val keys = data.getKeys("Charlie")
        assert(keys.isEmpty())
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: `subscribe()` need to return a `CompletableFuture<Void> `